# Suppose that $u,v \in \mathbb R^n$ with $u,v$ not equal to $\mathbf 0$, and let $A= I + uv^\top$.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

a) Show that $1+v^\top u$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $u$ its eigenvector.

b) Define the subspace $S$ of $\mathbb  R^{n}$ to be $$S=\{x \in \mathbb R^{n}\mid v^\top x=0\}= \operatorname {null}(v^\top).$$

Find the dimesion of $S$.

Comment: Hey BOB, welcome to math.stackexchange. It would be cool if you could share your thoughts about the problem, and maybe can even show things you have already tried. Our website's policy concerning self study questions is that you share your thoughts with us. This can be just as simple as telling us exactly all things you already know, all definitions, theorems, formulas, things you think you might need to use, but maybe don't see how to apply them and fit the pieces together.

Comment: Absolutely, I  figure it's dealing with the characteristic equation (A-lamda*I)x=0, and some properties of the use of the transpose. I have worked out many different variations but haven't came to get the final answer. I tried substituting the values of lamda an A into this equation and working it out, tried using the determinant, and a few other operations. I just haven't been able to prove that 1+(v^T)u  in the eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, just note that $v^Tu \in \Bbb{R}$. Thus we have
$$
Au = (I + uv^T)\ u = u + (uv^T)u = u + u(v^Tu) = (1 + v^Tu)\ u
$$
which by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) means that $u$ is an eigenvector, corresponding to the eigenvalue $1 + v^Tu$.

---

For the second part, first extend $v$ to a basis $\{v,u_1,\dotsc,u_{n-1}\}$. Applying the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) we can make this into an orthonormal basis $\{v',w_1,\dotsc,w_{n-1}\}$ such that $v = \|v\| v'$. Since clearly
$$
\text{null}(v) = \text{null}(v')
$$
and since $(v')^Tw_i = 0$ for every $i \in \{1,\dotsc,n-1\}$ by construction, it follows that the dimension of $\text{null}(v)$ is $n-1$.

**Alternatively** let $\{e_1,\dotsc,e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$ and observe that up to a change of basis we may assume that $v = e_1 = (1,0,\dotsc,0)$. Clearly $e_2,\dotsc,e_n$ are orthogonal to $e_1$, thus $\text{null}(e_1)$ must have dimension $n-1$.

Comment: That makes so much sense, I had Au but I had it in the characteristic form Au-Lamda*I, and with all the algebraic manipulation it wasn't working right. Thank you. Just to ask is there another way to verify part b without using Gram-Schmidt process? Is there a intuitive way of looking at this part of the question?

Comment: You can think of it geometrically: if $x = (x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$ and $0 \neq v = (v_1,\dotsc,v_n)$, then $0 = v^T x = v_1 x_1 + \dotsc + v_n x_n$ is the equation of a hyperplane in $\Bbb{R}^n$, which is an $n-1$ dimensional subspace.

Comment: Thank you again, that help me understand this hw problem a lot better. I thank you for your time.

Comment: I added a shorter, less constructive proof for the second part.

Answer (score 1):

For b) This is one more alternative:
One can think of

$v^t$ as a linear transformation $\Bbb{R^n}$ to $\Bbb{R}$

$v$ being non zero implies rank of this transformation is$1$ so nullity is $n-1$.